# How to use multiple jar versions in servicemix

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi

I'm using `apache-servicemix-4.4.1 -fuse-03-06`
I have two version of same jar, `Model-1.0.jar` and `Model-2.0.jar`. Both have same class with different methods. In my deploy folder I have two blueprint projects `blueprint-one.jar` and  `blueprint-two.jar`. `blueprint-one.jar` uses `Model-1.0.jar` and `blueprint-two.jar` uses `Model-2.0.jar`

but when deploy both jars in deploy folder I'm getting `NoSuchMethod exception`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the OSGi import|export and have your 2 blueprint bundles import the exact version they use (or a range). So blueprint A import [1.0,2). And blueprint B import [2.0,3). Then eg A imports all 1.x versions. And B imports all 2.x version. You can google about the OSGi syntax for the version ranges.

And your model bundles must export the version number they are, eg 1.0.0, and the other is 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have the same classloader load different versions of the same class. Are you not able to get blueprint 1 to use model 2?

Comment: I'm not able to get blueprint-one to use Model-1.0.jar. I desperately need to use multiple versions of same class. Is there a way to specify the version number in camel context or in bean declaration section?

Comment: and they need to run under the same camel instance?